# Getting Elasticsearch Data into HDFS Easily

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hdfs

We have had an Elasticsearch cluster on premise for almost 2 years now and wanted to do some more advanced analytics and such with the log data contained there as well as other disparate data sources.

Our focus is Syslogs which are in Elasticsearch. Each day generates ~100gb of syslog data - each day is it's own index. We have some applicaiton logs too, but if I can solve this problem for syslog, I can easily solve it for other data movement issues.

Which leads me to my question. For my analysis, we are using Spark 2.1.1 with the Python API. I'd like to have all of the syslog data, for say, 2 weeks in HDFS so we can do two things:

1. Avoid latency with communicating between our Spark/Hadoop Cluster
2. Speed up things on our machine learning jobs
3. Down the road I want to start using Parquet for my data, so if I have the data being pulled from ES, I can do whatever I want to with it later.

Now, my question - what is the best method for pulling such large amounts of data from ES and putting it in HDFS? I have an example in PySpark of doing some basic queries, but when I try and pull an entire index (100gb daily generated index) into an RDD, I get out of memory errors. I have reached out to Elasticsearch support, but am being told this is a problem I need to solve on the Hadoop/Spark side and they don't support that.

We have setup the "ES-Hadoop Connector", which does give me some framework to work from, though understanding the documentation is really a challenge. There are connectors for several of the components of the Hadoop ecosystem (HIVE, Spark, Hadoop, etc.). I'm not sure if there is a solution there, or if there is something better to do. I'm new to this, so excuse any questions that have obvious answers. I'm looking for some guidance and some specific recommendations (pointers to specific examples with setup and code would be amazing, if possible). My goals for this are:

1. Get ~2 weeks worth of syslogs in HDFS (I'd like this to be a rolling 2 weeks)
2. Create a minimal load on the Elasticsearch system
3. Whatever methods there are, it would be nice to automate this so every day a new index is ingested and the oldest is removed. This is not a hard requirement, but just a nice to have.

Thanks for any help, suggestions or examples you can point me toward.

**EDIT / ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I wanted to add some code here to explain what I am trying to do. The process is taking an extremely long time to complete, and even after hours, doesn't show an progress, so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Here is how I launch Py Spark:

```
pyspark --jars=/sysadmin/hadoop/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.3/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.3.jar --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 8G --driver-memory 50G
```

Then, I do a couple of things, I set the esconf, create the RDD and then try and just save it as text to HDFS:

```
>>> esconf = {"es.net.http.auth.user":"XXXXX","es.net.http.auth.pass":"XXXXX","es.resource":"logstash-syslog-2017.10.11", "es.query":"?q=*","es.read.field.include":"message","es.nodes":"server0005","es.net.ssl":"true"}
>>> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=esconf)
>>> rdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/spark/logstash-syslog-2017.10.11.txt")
```

Now, the RDD comes back and if I do a `take(1)` from the RDD, it takes a while, but I can get back the top 10 results. On that 10 record set, I can save it, works like a charm. On the full RDD, though, this is just taking forever. I'm not really sure what I should expect, but I can't imagine on a 10-node cluster with 64gb of RAM and 8 cores per box that this should take hours.

Comment: Do you want to export the data, or do you want it to be processed via Hadoop jobs? If you hit memory issues in Spark, you obviously will need to get more executors and increase their memory settings. Otherwise, with ES-Hadoop you can make a Hive table, then insert into an HDFS table from an ES defined table

Comment: The alternative is  send the syslog data to logstash, have logstash output to HDFS and Elasticsearch

Comment: @cricket_007 - What I'd like to do is take those indexes and dump them into HDFS so I can deal with the data there. Since syslog index represents an entire day (~100gb), it would probably be wise to break this up into smaller partitions when putting it into HDFS so processing is faster, but I don't know if this is a good strategy or not. Right now I am limited to 10 data nodes with 64gb of RAM and 8 core processors. I was suggested HIVE initially, but then told if I was using Spark I should just query ES directly. Do you have any suggestions or recommendations on a proper methodology for this?

Comment: I believe I already gave you my recommendations. Logstash can send new data to HDFS. Spark,  Hive, Pig  does not really matter. For Spark, you must increase the default  executor memory. Spark won't use HDFS unless you write the data there, and it won't keep low load on Elasticsearch

Comment: @cricket_007 -  An example of what I am trying to do is what William Benton presented at the 2016 Spark Summit. He stated that he dumped all of the data from ES to HDFS and used Parquet. I'd like to do something similar. [Bill Benton Talk](https://spark-summit.org/2016/events/analyzing-log-data-with-apache-spark/) He did't really go into how he did this. I did reach out to him, but haven't heard back.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I do appreciate the recommendations - just trying to wrap my head around this, that's all. Thanks for the feedback on this, it helps.

Comment: I assume this is your starting point?
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-read

Comment: @cricket_007 -Yes, we have a support contract with Elastic and that was the first page I was pointed to when I contacted them. I have been over it quite a bit.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? And your spark submit command?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes - give me a bit of time to do this - I need to get into my systems at work to grab all of it. I'll follow up with the code. Thanks!

Comment: @cricket_007 - So I tried a couple of things, per your suggestion and found a good long term solution based on some feedback I got on Reddit. To solve my initial problem, I had to inclrease the executor memory and add more of them, so I ended up giving it 10 executors and giving each 16gb of RAM. That allowed me to sucessfully read in an entire index. Now I just need to work on formatting it and writing it to HDFS. For the long term solution I was pointed to Apache NiFi, which seems to be exactly what I was looking for. If you post your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an example in PySpark of doing some basic queries, but when I try and pull an entire index (100gb daily generated index) into an RDD, I get out of memory errors

Spark doesn't allocate much memory to your jobs by default, so yes, when dealing with that much data, you'll get OOM errors.

Here's the key properties you should be concerned with and their defaults.

- `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` - `false`
- `spark.executor.instances` - `2`
- `spark.executor.memory` - `1g`
- `spark.driver.cores` - `1`

If your Spark jobs are running under YARN cluster management, you also need to consider your YARN container sizes. When running in cluster mode, the Application Master will be the Spark driver container. In my experience, unless your Spark code is calling `collect()` to send data back through the driver, it doesn't need that much memory itself.

I would try first increasing the Executor memory, and then the number of executors.   If you enable dynamic allocation, then you can consider not specifying the executor amount, but it does set a lower boundary to start with.

ES-Hadoop provides many connectors to extract data, but it all comes down to preference. If you know SQL, use Hive. Pig is simpler to run than Spark. Spark is very memory heavy, which might not work well in some clusters.

You mention NiFi in your comments, but that is still a Java process, and prone to OOM errors. Unless you have a NiFi cluster, you'll have a single process somewhere pulling 100 GB through a FlowFile on disk before writing to HDFS.

If you need a Snapshot of a whole Index, Elasticsearch provides [HDFS support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-snapshots.html) for such a feature. I'm unsure what data format that is, though, or if Hadoop processes can read it.

Comment: Thanks! On your last point, by default the ES-Hadoop connector can do snapshots for ES to HDFS for backup, but would still be a lucene index. The other option is I'd have my ES team create a repository for the connector, which essentially allows me to perform a REST query to ES that will kick off a job on ES  to push data to HDFS, but I am still unclear what format that comes in. I assume JSON, since that is what typically comes out of ES. My goal was to get things in columnar storage, as that is more suitable to Spark and Hadoop, so something like NiFi seems like a good choice.

Comment: Yeah, Nifi can put ORC or Parquet just as well as Pig, Hive, or Spark

Comment: I added code, per your previous request - I didn't want to start a new question on this, as I am still trying to resolve some issues. I added the code and new information at the end of the question under "EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFO". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You would need to watch the Spark UI to know what is taking a long time

Comment: It's literally the saveAsTextFile() stage. I removed anything else, so literally, query Elastic and store that into an RDD (only the messages of syslog), and then do a save. I'm not even trying to reparition or coalesce or anything. That last command `rdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/spark/logstash-syslog-2017.10.11.txt")` has been running for over 3 hours now... seems like a long time just to save data to HDFS....

Comment: How many executors? I'm guessing only one? 100Gb from Elasticsearch, through one Java process, then over to HDFS wouldn't be fast.

Comment: I'm using 10 executors - based on my research, I believe that I need to dedicate more memory to the driver, so I gave it 50gb (all my boxes have 64gb). I'm not quite sure if that driver memory is distributed or if I need to make sure I have all that memory on one box - but since I'm not doing any sort of `collect()` or anything in this process, it shouldn't matter. Each executor has been given 8gb of memory. Will giving this more executors speed this up or slow it down? I'm going back to thinking a tool for data movement like NiFi is sounding better and better.....

Comment: There is only one one driver. I can't imagine giving only the driver more memory would help much... I haven't used the Elasticsearch Spark connector, so I could be wrong, but each executor needs to run the exact same Elasticsearch query, pulling all the index data... Nifi is not distributed by default, but feel free to try it. It's no different than writing your own Java code using the Elasticsearch Java SDK, just gives a simple GUI

Comment: That's a good point, but I think the benefit of the NiFi thing is I can automate it out of Kafka and pull smaller chunks of the data so the movement doesn't take so long. When I issue the `rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=esconf)`, that run pretty quick, so my assumption is that doesn't actually pull any data until I run something like `take()` or `saveAsTextFile()` at which point it seems to start querying ES. Am I correct on that assumption?

Comment: That's correct. Spark is lazy until you do an action like those. If you're using Kafka, Spark Streaming would work. Your question didn't mention that

Comment: Yeah, down the road Spark Streaming is an option, I'm just not there yet, still getting my bearings. Right now I'd like to get a large data set in HDFS so I can get my machine learning model trained. That way I don't have to put a strain on my ES cluster, since that data would be in HDFS. Streaming is definitely something I need to look into...

Comment: Solved my speed problem. I needed to increase my scroll size to the max (10000). I think the default is 50. After running for 9+ hours, I killed the job, increased the scroll size and it finished a whole index in 30 minutes. :-) I'll post the updated code in a bit.